# Create a section of a pie chart in css

Tags: html, css, pie-chart

How can I create a section of a pie chart?

For exemple, We can create 25% using `border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;` and 100% using `border-radius: 20px;`.

I'm trying to create a circle with different color around it in css to explain different portions. In the middle I'll put a $ sign in a white circle so only the border will be colored.

Unfortunately I never played with circles and there's not much people talking about that on the internet.

Eventually I will animate it so it will be all white and slowly from 0% it will start to display all category but that's not the point right now.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is HTML5 Canvas an option http://imgflip.com/piemaker

Comment: If you are using .Net I can help you with this.

Comment: @Reddy No .Net for me, but thank you very much for your offer! :)

Comment: Check my answer to see if the works for you

Answer (score 3):

Ok how about this solution

Creates a Div with borders radius, exaggerate to be a circle

```
div{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius: 328px;
}
```

Then creates the selected part base on gradients

```
.percent_50  {
    background-image : -webkit-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 200 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    background-image : -moz-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 200 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    background-image : -ms-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 200 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    border:1px solid black;
}
.percent_25  {
    background-image : -webkit-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 0 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    background-image : -moz-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 0 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    background-image : -ms-gradient(radial, 200 200, 0, 0 0, 200,
        from(red), to(red));
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

The Result

[image: Pie pure css]

http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/wdMYa/

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/wdMYa/1/ <--smaller

Comment: Thank you @Jorge, I prefer CSS over Canvas to be honest, but I'll see if it's possible to make other % like 15% for exemple. Canvas looks like more appropriate for this kind of manipulation though :( (Upvoted)

Comment: I looked on the internet based on what you've done, I found this: http://www.javabeat.net/2013/09/pie-chart-css3-html/ Once you know how to make it, it's kind of easy ;)